# Database compare tools

Tags: database, diff

My company has a number of relatively small Access databases (2-5MB) that control our user assisted design tools.  Naturally these databases evolve over time as data bugs are found and fixed and as the schema changes to support new features in the tools.  Can anyone recommend a database diff tool to compare both the data and schema from one version of the database to the next?  Any suggestions will be appreciated: free, open source, or commercial.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I use Red Gate Sql Compare for comparing schemas. It also has an interesting feature that allows you to save a snapshot of the schema which you can then use in later diffs. for example compare the schema of today with the schema of a month ago.

Answer (score 1):

I use ApexSQL Diff.  It is an excellent tool for doing just what you're describing...compare schema, compare data, generate change scripts.  It not free, but it works well.

*NOTE: ApexSQL Diff only works with SQL Server.*

Answer (score 0):

We never actually purchased it as we ended up using SQL Server 2005, but DBDiff seemed to do the trick: http://www.dkgas.com/downdbdiff.cgi

It works with any ODBC compatible DB.

Answer (score 0):

I've used [Total Access Detective](http://www.fmsinc.com/MicrosoftAccess/DatabaseCompare.html) in the past and it did the trick. It's a while ago though so you might want to investigate first...

Answer (score 0):

If you're looking for a free alternative to Red Gate's most excellent SQL Compare, you might want to check SQLDBDigg made by [SQLDBTools](http://www.sqldbtools.com/). It's what I used until I caved and bought SQL Compare.

Answer (score 0):

It's not a perfect solution, but I often export both databases as txt/SQL files and then use a diff program, such as the one that comes with [TortoiseSVN](http://tortoisesvn.tigris.org). You can then see all of the differences. It doesn't automatically create the SQL though to sync the dbs.

Answer (score 0):

http://www.diffkit.org

Features

High performance, for large datasets (+10MM rows).

Very low memory overhead, even on very large datasets.

High quality-- comprehensive embedded regression test suite for the application/framework.

Java run everywhere (tm) — Linux, Solaris, OS X, Windows, etc.

Cross database-- Oracle, MySQL, DB2, and any JDBC datasource.

Command-line driven; no GUI needed; can run in headless environments.

XML configuration file driven.

Free Open Source Software.

Apache License, Version 2.0.

Clean Object Oriented Design make extension easy.

Easily embeddable as a Java library (jar).